# Intercepting Checkbox Click to Confirm the Change

Tags: jquery, checkbox, click

I have a checkbox and as soon as it is clicked I'm going to submit an AJAX request to update a field. However, first I'd like to call `confirm` to make sure that this is what they want.

This does not work:

```
$(".mycheckbox")
    .live("click",
        function(){
            if(!confirm("Sure about that?")){ return false; }
            $.post($(this.form).attr("action")+".js",
                   $(this).serialize()+"&_method=put",
                   null, 
                   "script");
        }
    )
```

Comment: @cwolves thanks for you comment. I didn't know that before. thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of `return false`:

```
function(ev){
    if(!confirm("Sure about that?")){
        ev.preventDefault();
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I tried this before and thought it didn't work, but now it does. Oh well.

Comment: It didn't work before, I just secretly fixed your computer so that it would.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm thinking too. Websockets FTW.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to wrap your confirm around the post:

```
$(".mycheckbox")
    .live("click",
        function(){
            if( confirm("Sure about that?")){ 
                  $.post($(this.form).attr("action")+".js",
                   $(this).serialize()+"&_method=put",
                   null, 
                   "script");
             }
        }
    )
```

Comment: confirm is a blocking call so the `return false` will work fine, I think he wants to prevent the checkbox from changing, not sure though

Comment: Yes, I wanted to prevent it from changing.