# Confirm box after checking Checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox, confirm

I've been trying different methods for hours based on what I've found here, to no avail. Can someone please steer me in the right direction? When checking or unchecking a checkbox I want to throw the confirmation and then have the checkbox return either check or uncheck based on the users selections. Thank you!

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function(){
     var checked = $("input:checked").length; 
    if (checked == 0){ 
if(confirm('Are you sure you want to discontinue this program?')){
    (':checkbox:checked').removeAttr('checked');
}
    }  else

    { 
if(confirm('Are you sure you want to resume use of this program?'))            
(':checkbox:checked').attr('checked');
    }
```

HTML

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="input" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
    <td>Because We Care</td>
   </tr>
      <tr>
                     <td><input name="" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
                     <td>Some Unused Program</td>
                     </tr>
```

Comment: please google properly before posting your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944889/intercepting-checkbox-click-to-confirm-the-change

Answer (score 8):

There are some syntax & logic flaws in your code, try this:

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function(){
    var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
    if(checked) {
        if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to resume use of this program?')){         
            $(this).removeAttr('checked');
        }
    } else if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to discontinue this program?')){
        $(this).attr("checked", "checked");
    }
}​);​
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dfKEZ/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and explanation! However, I cannot get the confirm boxes to happen when checking the checkboxes. Is there something else I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Reporting back to Des ... Thank you! I actually got it to work. Stripped this down to one line of code at a time watching for errors and eventually I got it. It's all the brackets that hang me up! I sure appreciate your help!

Comment: **attr** and **removeAttr** not working for in firefox. we can use

**$(this).prop("checked", false);**

**$(this).prop("checked", true);**

Answer (score 1):

When the listener is executed the checkbox is already checked or unchecked. What you should do is:

- when the user confirms do nothing
- when the user does not confirm undo what has been done

Answer (score 0):

This should be exactly what you're looking for:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<input id="chkTest" type="checkbox" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#chkTest").change(function(evt){
        var attr = $(evt.target).attr("checked")
        if (typeof attr !== 'undefined' && attr !== false){
            alert("Checked");
        }
        else{
            alert("Not Checked");
        }
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, although neither of the above helps me get the confirmed box. I'm understanding the code from des more than blang32. Any explanations would be appreciated. Very new to both js and jquery ... trying in earnest to learn both. It's hard! :D